# What does this Lambda operation do?

Tags: java, lambda

I missed a day of class and can't find someone to explain this part of an assignment to me?
What does the `((a, b) -> a + b, (a, b) -> a * b);` do in

```
Ring<Integer> r = new Ring<Integer>((a, b) -> a + b, (a, b) -> a * b)
```

I don't think the context for Ring is needed, just care about the expression.

Comment: Are you asking what the `->` syntax is? (Is this Java?)

Comment: Moment, for some reason the formatting is destroying the actual line of code. 
I'm asking what purpose this ((a,b) -> a+b, (a,b) -> a*b) serves

Comment: Pleas specify a programming language.

Answer (score 1):

`(a,b) -> a+b` is an anonymous function taking 2 parameters `a` and `b` and returning `a+b`. Likewise `(c,d) -> c*d` is an anonymous function taking 2 parameters `c` and `d` and returning `c*d`.

The class Ring takes 2 functions as parameters in the constructor and binds them to later execute them when needed. Google java lambdas if you're curious how function objects are implemented in java.